# React Auth Router v6

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router

I am trying to build a simple react app with authentication logic.. the repository can be found [here](https://github.com/RazvanCretu/tracker-front)

I am facing issues trying to get to `/reports` as the app keeps redirecting me to `/login` page even if the useEffect hook runs and authenticates the user..

What could be missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your return from `PrivateRoute` should be changed.
In the beginning `isAuthenticated` is false and `loading` is true

`isAuthenticated && !loading === false`

So your `<Navigate replace to="/login" />` is returned.

Instead you can move loading state somewhere above to have it like this

```js
function PrivateRoute({ children }) {
  /* ... */

  if (loading) {
    return <SomeSpinner />
  }

  return isAuthenticated
    ? children
    : <Navigate replace to="/login" />;
}
```

And you will not have the redirect immediately, but will wait for loading

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't work.. Still redirected to `/login`